# Does the past perfect carry this idea?

Tags: meaning

> Once the film was finished and released, one of the young producers **had stepped** in as Adam's manager. I'm not sure what, if any actual effort was made to get these recordings on a major label release but eventually we found ourselves with about  half of an album  of very well-recorded songs, and decided  to record some new stuff Adam had been writing.

NOTES WRITTEN ON  THE RECORD SLEEVE (Adam Roth and his band of men) HOZAC ARCHIVALS

We can think that the stepping happened before the film was finished (cf past perfect). This seems strange because beginning the sentence by "Once" we can logically expect to continue with an event that took place after. This is not the case . The young producer had become the manager before the film was finished .

I think that the writer used past perfect to indicate a relation of cause, because they had a  manager(one of the young producer)  that  the band decided to record some new  stuff. May be the manager gave them  confidence. In the eventuality that an effort had been  made to get the first recordings  to a major label, he would  certainly have helped

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If I am right to think the pp is used to indicate the cause  and if all  I have just written seems right for  native speaker

Comment: You seem to have extra information which you are not revealing. Specifically why are you sure the young producer stepped in before the film was finished when the text clearly states the opposite?

Comment: No I am not sure  but because the past perfect  indicates an event  that happened before the one written in past simple . No I don't have extra information . In fact I don't understand why the past perfect is used in this case after once if  the stepping happens after

Comment: One of the young producers had stepped in once the film was finished and released. The producers stepping in precedes the film being finished and released.

Comment: Is there more context before this? If so, please edit your question to include it. If not, it's just bad grammar, but the kind that some native speakers might produce.